# Analyzing functions with absolute values

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have a question. I am having trouble analyzing functions with absolute values, for example the following:

$$\frac{\ln{|x|}}{x}-x+1$$

Now, what I usually would do if I got a function with absolute values is try to break it down, for example if I had simply $|x|$ I know it's $ x, x\ge0$ and $-x, x<0$. But since I have $\ln|x|$ I don't know how to proceed.

Firstly, I know that the function is defined for all real x except $0$. I know that the function is zero at $-1, 1$, but if I try to calculate the sign of the function (where it's above and below the $x$-asis) I have trouble because I don't know how to break $\ln{|x|}$ into smaller parts.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln|x|}{x}-x+1$$
is the same as
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\ln(-x)}{x}-x+1&;\;x<0\\
\frac{\ln x}{x}-x+1&;\;x>0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\log|-5|=\log|5|$, for instance. The graph is symmetrical:

[image: Graph of modulus]

We know that $\log x$ is negative if $0<x<1$. Hence, $\log |x|$ is negative if...